# New Angular project won't compile with strict mode

Tags: angular, typescript

Generated Angular project with CLI
Modified `tsconfig`, added strict options

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  }
}
```

When running `ng serve` I get following error:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,29): error TS7016: Could not find
>   a declaration file for module 'util'.
>   'D:/proj/node_modules/util/util.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install @types/util` if it
>   exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare
>   module 'util';`

I tried `npm install` suggested - this module does not exist. 
I also tried to delete node_modules and do `npm install`. Same thing. Any pointers?

**EDIT**

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { isUndefined } from "util";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "Portal";
}
```

Comment: This code is not generated by Angular CLI. So you, or someone in your team chose to add the unused `isUndefined` import. Just remove it.

Comment: Well, `strict` implies `noImplicitAny`, and this `util` library is likely not in TypeScript and doesn't have a definition file. Either generate a definition file, or remove it and use `typeof variable === "undefined"` instead of depending on a third party library.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I did not add that line, but I did play with some code, so it's possible VSCode added it automatically?

Comment: What version of of the CLI? I would also delete the import of "isUndefined"

Comment: I have a similar problem like this, I use `"noImplicitAny": true`, which comes with `"strict": true` and `"skipLibCheck": true` which should ignore problems in the @types folder, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1: **Delete node_modules**

2: Run **npm install**

3: Run **ng serve --aot=false**

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out or remove the following line from main.ts (added by the upgrade process):

```
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

might be resolved your problem

Answer (score -4):

Declare variables before assigning any values in strict mode:

```
var title = "portal";
```

or

```
let title = "portal"
```

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.